# ¿Cómo pasar el parámetro a una UDF en SQLSERVER?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Buen día,

Estoy desarrollando una rutina de sql, que a grandes rasgos debe calcular el costo total de envío. El problema que tengo es que al ejecutar la rutina no pasa el parámetro a la UDF que ya tengo desarrollada y por lo tanto el resultado que tiene es erróneo.

El código de mi consulta es el siguiente:

```
--DECLARACIÓN DE VARIABLE Y LLENAD DE FILAS
DECLARE @FILAS INT
SET @FILAS=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #SHIPPED_ORDERS)

--WHILE @FILAS>0
    
    set nocount on;

    --SE DECLARA LA VARIABLE ORDNUM PARA OBTENER EL NÚMERO DEL PRIMER ORDER NO
    DECLARE @ORDNUM AS INT, @NEW_ORDER INT, @fnordnum int
    SET @ORDNUM=(SELECT TOP 1 ORDNUM FROM #SHIPPED_ORDERS ORDER BY ORDNUM ASC);
    --PRIMERO EVALÚA SI YA EXISTE LA ORDEN DENTRO DE LA TABLA ORDERS_SHIPPED
    SET @NEW_ORDER=(SELECT Order_No FROM ORDERS_SHIPPED WHERE Order_No=@ORDNUM)
    
    select @ORDNUM

SELECT TOP 1
    Order_No,
    Source_Doc,
    Source_PO,
    CONVERT(DATE,Import_Date,101) AS Import_Date,
    CONVERT(DATE,Ship_Date,101) AS Ship_Date,
    Shipped,
    Length,
    Width,
    Height,
    Weight,
    freight,
    DBO.FN_FREIGHT_COST(@ORDNUM) AS Freight,
    Service
FROM RAW_MULTISHIPPED
WHERE Order_No=@ORDNUM
```

Y el código de la UDF es éste:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_FREIGHT_COST
    (
        @ORDNUM int
    )
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN 
    --DECLARACIÓN DE VARIABLES
    DECLARE @Q_TRACKS INT, @V_TRACKS INT, @FILAS_ORDER INT
    DECLARE @FREIGHT_SUM MONEY, @FREIGHT_COST MONEY
    DECLARE @T_ORDER TABLE(ORDNUM INT, TRACKING VARCHAR(50), COST MONEY)

    --LLENAMOS LAS VARIABLES
    SET @Q_TRACKS=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Tracking_No) AS TRACKINGS FROM RAW_MULTISHIPPED WHERE Order_No=@ORDNUM)--INDICA EL NÚMERO DE TRACKINGS DISTINTOS POR ORDEN
    SET @V_TRACKS=(SELECT COUNT(Tracking_No) AS TRACKINGS FROM RAW_MULTISHIPPED WHERE Order_No=@ORDNUM)--CUENTA TODOS LOS TRACKINGS DE LA ORDEN
    SET @FREIGHT_SUM=(SELECT SUM(Freight) FROM RAW_MULTISHIPPED WHERE Order_No=@ORDNUM)
    
    --CONDICIONAL PARA SACAR EL COSTO DE ENVÍO REAL
    IF @Q_TRACKS=1
        SET @FREIGHT_COST=@FREIGHT_SUM/@V_TRACKS

    ELSE --IGUAL O MAYOR A 2
        --INSERTA DATOS EN LA VARIABLE TABLAS
        INSERT INTO @T_ORDER
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                Order_No,
                Tracking_No,
                Freight
            FROM RAW_MULTISHIPPED
            WHERE Order_No=@ORDNUM

            --SUMA EL MONTO DEL FREIGHT COST
            SET @FREIGHT_COST=(SELECT SUM(COST) FROM @T_ORDER)

            --BORRAMOS EL CONTENIDO DE LA TABLA @T_ORDER
            DELETE FROM @T_ORDER

    RETURN @FREIGHT_COST
END
```

El resultado me debe dar la suma o el promedio, dependiendo el caso, del costo de envío; espero me puedan ayudar con mi problema.

Saludos y gracias!!

Comment: Hay muchos problemas ahí, pero creo que ninguno es el que mencionas.

Comment: ¿Cuáles serían los problemas que puedes ver? Porque el resultado de la función me da nulo....y no entiendo por qué....

Comment: Estoy trabajando en una solución, pero necesito saber que pasa si tienes trackings repetidos combinados con trackings únicos en una orden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás tratando de resolver un problema de forma iterativa usando múltiples variables, cuando solo necesitamos simplificar la lógica.

Antes de pasar a la solución eficiente, te explico cual fue el problema con tu código. SQL Server no identifica bloques de código por indentación, por lo que necesitas `BEGIN...END` para delimitar el bloque de código que será afectado, en este caso, por el `IF...ELSE...`. De otro modo, la asignación `SET @FREIGHT_COST=(SELECT SUM(COST) FROM @T_ORDER)` siempre se ejecuta y sobreescribe el valor que habías asignado anteriormente.

Ahora, regresando a las mejores prácticas, es malo hacer múltiples consultas a la misma tabla con la misma condición para ir obteniendo distintos valores. Cada consulta es una lectura y un plan de ejecución nuevo que consumen recursos. Lo ideal es hacer la llamada a la tabla una sola vez para obtener toda la información posible de la fila o conjunto de filas que necesitemos.

Otro detalle es que borras los datos de una variable tipo tabla, lo cual es innecesario ya que esa tabla desaparecerá cuando termine la ejecución o cuando se pierda el foco de la función. Es simplemente un proceso innecesario que consume recursos.

Finalmente, dejo un ejemplo de la función hecha de forma sencilla, junto con datos de prueba y un ejemplo de como usarla. Si te fijas, uso el nombre de la columna en vez de la variable, para que la función pueda ser usada con múltiples órdenes a la vez.

```
--Crear datos de prueba
CREATE TABLE RAW_MULTISHIPPED(
    Order_No int,
    Tracking_No int,
    Freight money,
    Descripcion varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO RAW_MULTISHIPPED
VALUES( 1, 1, 30, 'Suma de envíos distintos'),
      ( 1, 2, 50, 'Suma de envíos distintos'),
      ( 2, 3, 22, 'Promedio de envíos iguales'),
      ( 2, 3, 28, 'Promedio de envíos iguales'),
      ( 3, 4, 23, 'Suma de promedios por envío'),
      ( 3, 4, 23, 'Suma de promedios por envío'),
      ( 3, 5, 24, 'Suma de promedios por envío');
GO

GO
CREATE FUNCTION FN_FREIGHT_COST
    (
        @ORDNUM int
    )
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT SUM(Freight) Freight --Sumamos los costos por envío
            FROM (
                SELECT Tracking_No, --Obtenemos el promedio por envío
                        AVG( Freight) Freight
                FROM RAW_MULTISHIPPED
                WHERE Order_No = @ORDNUM
                GROUP BY Tracking_No) av);

END
GO


SELECT TOP 10
    Order_No,
    freight,
    DBO.FN_FREIGHT_COST(Order_No) AS Freight,
    Descripcion
FROM RAW_MULTISHIPPED


GO
--Para limpiar mi base de datos
--DROP TABLE RAW_MULTISHIPPED;
--DROP FUNCTION FN_FREIGHT_COST
```

Comment: ¿Cuál duda tienes?

Comment: Luis buenas tardes, me queda una duda con respecto al código que me pones. 

Mi duda es cómo distingue cuando debe sumar y cuándo sacar el promedio...mi duda se centra en ésta parte del código:

    RETURN (SELECT SUM(Freight) Freight --Sumamos los costos por envío
            FROM (
                SELECT Tracking_No, --Obtenemos el promedio por envío
                        AVG( Freight) Freight
                FROM RAW_MULTISHIPPED
                WHERE Order_No = @ORDNUM
                GROUP BY Tracking_No) av);

Comment: Creo que la respuesta a mi última pregunta es la siguiente:
Se suman los promedios debido a que están agrupados por el tracking number, por lo tanto, no importa si existen 3 tracking numbers distintos y además estén repetidos; al sacar el promedio de cada uno de ellos se suman y tengo el mismo resultado....¿estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Es correcto lo que dices.